# Including multiple modules in a single application

Tags: apache-flex, graph

I have developed an application that loads modules where an application calls 4 different modules that generates pie chart using xml returned from server. When I include a single module in that application using moduleloader, it works fine. When i include 2 modules, it is less efficient. And when I include more than 2 modules , then the application becomes totally functionless. Is is that the flex application can load only a single module at a time or it can load any numer of modules using Module loader?

Answer (score 0):

Flex can load multiple modules at a time, but depending on the amount of XML data and the module itself, you may see some performance hits.  Have you tried the profiler in Flex/Flash Builder?  It will show you where you are eating up memory and what you might be able to do to improve the performance.